# Display Properties in Custom Order in Visual Studio Debugger

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debugging

In Visual Studio, is it possible to customize the order in which properties are displayed when inspected in the debugger?

Here's an example of a class where I'd really like StartDate and EndDate to appear next to each other, even though they are separated alphabetically .

[image: example]

Other debugger options are customizable through attributes like the [`DebuggerDisplayAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerdisplayattribute.aspx), so I was hopeful that another such attribute would exist for DisplayOrder.

```cs
[DebuggerDisplay("{Name}")]
public class Rule
{
    public string Name;
    public int MaxAge;
    public DateTime StartDate;
    public DateTime EndDate;
}
```

In an *ideal world*, I'd like the ability to order the properties in the inspector in the order that I have defined on the class (even if that requires setting an debugger order attribute incrementally on each property) so the display would look like this:

[image: ideal debugger]

Comment: I don't think so... the only debugger attributes I know are `DebuggerDisplay`, `DebuggerBrowsable` and `DebuggerTypeProxy`. Not saying it's impossible, I just don't know the way, if any (it'd be a nice feature tho)

Comment: I suppose you could write an add-in and hook the event that shows this information but this will be serious over-kill for what you want.

Comment: If the problem is that the type is too big, you could create a subtype with just the main properties you want (and a property linking to the actual full object), and use `DebuggerTypeProxy`. Something like the example in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228992(v=vs.110).aspx). This should only show some properties at first, but allow you to "nest inside"

Comment: Or you could have a calculated property that shows a `StartDate + " - " + EndDate` string if you are willing to add a "debugging property" to your object. You could use `#if DEBUG` for it

Comment: @KyleMit I'm not sure even the runtime debugging symbols account (or can account) for the order in which members were written. Yeah, an attribute could be used, but guess it was not that much of a feature request :-) . I'd go with the "extra members with `#if DEBUG`" solution if I was you

Comment: May I ask why is this necessary? I'm just curious and wondering why someone wants to order properties within debugger.

Comment: @Fka I think he explained it nicely enough. To have two related properties near each other (in his example, `StartDate` and `EndDate`). It aids on looking at those properties together at first glance. This could be very useful on potentially large objects with many properties. Specially when they scroll on your tiny window :-)

Comment: @Jcl OK, It might be useful. I didn't get it. Sorry.

Comment: @Fka, necessary...perhaps not.  helpful...sure!  Information is helpful when presented in a particular order.  Take any form on the internet or the current page you're looking at and scramble around the order and you'll find it takes longer to get that information.  I don't always use the debugger to glean something, but when I do, I'll almost always want the start time and end time next to each other...the same way I would want them to appear on the UI if I was going to put that information in a form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Pinnable Properties](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/pinnable-properties-debug-display-managed-objects-your-way/) in VS2019+ are a way to go currently, since you can pin your properties in correct order using the [image: pin] button inside the datatip.

However, in a more general, reusable approach, the `[DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.RootHidden)]` attribute can be used on an array of ordered property name and value pairs. This enables the debug view to 'flatten' the array root, listing the properties in correct order.

Further expanding on [KyleMit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28506057/1945988), and using reflection to load the list of members and fields, makes such a debug view reusable:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{Name}")]
[DebuggerTypeProxy(typeof(OrderedPropertiesView))]
public class Rule
{
    public string Name;
    public int MaxAge;
    public DateTime StartDate;
    public DateTime EndDate;        
}

public class OrderedPropertiesView
{
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.RootHidden)]
    public SimpleProperty[] Properties { get; }

    public OrderedPropertiesView(object input)
    {
        this.Properties = input.GetType()
            .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Select(prop => new SimpleProperty(prop, input))
            .ToArray();
    }

    [DebuggerDisplay("{Value}", Name = "{PropertyName,nq}")]
    public class SimpleProperty
    {
        public SimpleProperty(MemberInfo member, object input)
        {
            this.Value = GetValue(member, input);
            this.PropertyName = member.Name;
        }

        private object GetValue(MemberInfo member, object input)
        {
            switch (member)
            {
                case FieldInfo fi: return fi.GetValue(input);
                case PropertyInfo pi: return pi.GetValue(input);
                default: return null;
            }
        }

        public object Value { get; internal set; }
        public string PropertyName { get; internal set; }
    }
}
```

Which looks like this in the debugger:

[image: datatip with ordered 'properties']

The order of properties and fields might not be guaranteed with reflection, but since the view is only for debugging purposes, it should be enough. If not, `Properties` array can be constructed manually, limiting the reusability. In either case, `Properties` are not really properties, therefore expanding the `SimpleProperty` datatip looks like this:

[image: expanded datatip showing PropertyName and Value properties of SimpleProperty]

Notice that the property inspector [image: magnifyng glass] can only be used in the expanded `SimpleProperty.Value`, which might be an inconvenience.

Answer (score 4):

Just to run out the ball on [JCL's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28504884/#comment45329178_28504884) to use [`#if DEBUG`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx) with a caluclated property.  If you wanted some extra information in the debugger, you could add a field only when in debug mode like this:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{Name}")]
public class Rule
{
    public string Name;
    public int MaxAge;
    public DateTime StartDate;
    public DateTime EndDate;

#if DEBUG
    private string DateRange
    {
        get { return StartDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " - "+
                     EndDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        } 
    }
#endif

}
```

Which would look like this:

[image: debugger]

This gets information presented together, but will still add noise to the inspector.

Comment: I'd definitely use this one, and have upvoted it. Didn't want to write an answer since it does not "answer" the question (the answer to the question would be: "No", although I was not 100% sure of that "no" ;-) ), but if it works for you, I'd go this route. If you need to do this on several properties and want to have clean production code, I'd make the class partial and have a different `.cs` file for those debug properties (with a bit of work, you could just exclude that file from build on `Release` and even remove the `#if`s).

Comment: Both were solid suggestions given the technical limitations of .NET.  It was definitely worth tossing out ideas in the comments. Didn't mean to steal your answer points by posting, but did want to make sure they had the visibility the suggestions deserved.  I'm probably going to bounty this in a couple days to see if anyone has something even more elegant.

Comment: Don't worry about the points. I'm not on Stack Overflow for the points. I also found the question useful (that's why I gave it some thought) and if there is actually a "direct" way in Visual Studio, I'd like to know it :-)

Comment: Just another thought on this: if you go this route, I'd make the member private or at least, hide it from intellisense if this is a library used in other projects (using the `EditorBrowsableAttribute`). Using the attribute doesn't work if the project's source is in the current solution though, so I'd make it private: it should still show in the debugger (not sure if that'd issue a warning about unused fields though, but that could be disabled aswell, using `#pragma warning disable/restore 0169` around the field definition)

Comment: And one last thing, if you can use C# 6.0, you can write the property this like: `private string DateRange() => StartDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " - "+EndDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` which is gorgeous for these things :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could right click on the variables and 'Add Watch' and put them in order there.

[image]

Comment: It's a decent workaround, but I want this to be true for every time I ever look at this type in the inspector.  It kills me that I can't get `StartDate` next to `EndDate`, let alone before it. That's how I want to look at that type.

Comment: That could be a solution, however the "watches" are permanent (in the sense that they will keep there after the variable is out of scope), so if you do this a lot, the Watches window tends to be overcrowded, plus it applies only to some specific instance, not to the whole type. Yes, it "could" work under very specific circumstances, but there are better workarounds (involving modifying the type though, but if decorating it with attributes is not a problem, it shouldn't be modifying them aswell)

Answer (score 2):

Just to run out the ball on [JCL's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28504884/#comment45329060_28504884) to use [`DebuggerTypeProxyAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggertypeproxyattribute.aspx), you could add an internal class or a public class to act as a container for the debug view

You could use numbers to force the ordering of the the properties on the debugger view class without changing the API or performance of the runtime code.

Here's what the class would look like with the DebuggerTypeProxy:

```cs
[DebuggerDisplay("{Name}")]
[DebuggerTypeProxy(typeof (RuleDebugView))]
public class Rule
{
    public string Name;
    public int MaxAge;
    public DateTime StartDate;
    public DateTime EndDate;

    internal class RuleDebugView
    {
        public string _1_Name;
        public int _2_MaxAge;
        public DateTime _3_StartDate;
        public DateTime _4_EndDate;

        public RuleDebugView(Rule rule)
        {
            this._1_Name = rule.Name;
            this._2_MaxAge = rule.MaxAge;
            this._3_StartDate = rule.StartDate;
            this._4_EndDate = rule.EndDate;
        }
    }
}
```

Which would look like this in the debugger:

[image: debugger]

It's not the cleanest thing in the world, but it does do a little.